# knockout.js viewmodel stuck in loop calling WebAPI

Tags: knockout.js

I am new to Knockout.js and am using it to bind data from a WebAPI call.
I had a frustrating scenario where the getData() method was being called in an infinite loop.  After debugging, I found that it went away when I commented out console.log(self.activityLogs()). It does not cause loop issues when I leave it inside the getData method.

Can anyone explain what was going on here and why this infinite loop was happening?

```
$(function () {
    var ActivityLogViewModel = function () {
        self = this;
        self.activityLogs = ko.observableArray([]); //data
        getData();
        console.log(self.activityLogs());  // when this is here, it goes into infinite loop

        function getData() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/api/EnvironmentsApi/activityLogs",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    self.activityLogs(data);
                    console.log(self.activityLogs());
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    alert(error.status + "<--and--> " + error.statusText);
                }
            });
        }

        return {
            self: self
        }
    };
    ko.applyBindings(ActivityLogViewModel);
});
```

Not sure if this is relevant, but here is how I was binding it in my HTML table.

```
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: activityLogs">
        <tr>
            <td>b...</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Comment: `ko.applyBindings(new ActivityLogViewModel);`

Comment: Use `self.activityLogs.peek()` to read the data. Otherwise you're creating a dependency and Knockout will re-evaluate the entire `ActivityLogViewModel` function, causing an endless loop.

Answer (score 1):

I've created code snippet with your case. I did small changes: added `loopCount` variable to prevent infinite loop on the page during playing with it, and replaced Ajax call with Promise (but technically they behave the same).

In short: instead of `ko.applyBindings(ActivityLogViewModel);` you should do function call - `ko.applyBindings(ActivityLogViewModel());`. Because otherwise you're passing "function object" and this is not what the Knockout.js expects to work with. By some reason after every `activityLogs` reading it makes `ActivityLogViewModel` call and as a result it triggers new Ajax call, after that Ajax calls its `success` callback and the process starts once and once again.

Actually it's a good question why Knockout works in this way (we need to dig into its source code), but at least now we know how to prevent infinite loop problem.

```js
var loopCount = 0;

$(function () {
    var ActivityLogViewModel = function () {
        console.log('function triggered');
      
        self = this;
        self.activityLogs = ko.observableArray([]); //data 
        getData();
        console.log(self.activityLogs());  // when this is here, it goes into infinite loop

        function getData() {
            if (loopCount > 10) {
              return;
            }
          
            var requestPromise = $.Deferred();

            requestPromise.done(function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                self.activityLogs(data);
                console.log(self.activityLogs());
              
                loopCount++;
            });

            setTimeout(function() { requestPromise.resolve([1, 2, 3]); }, 100);
        }

        return {
            self: self
        }
    };

    ko.applyBindings(ActivityLogViewModel);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<tbody data-bind="foreach: activityLogs">
        <tr>
            <td>Item</td>
        </tr>
</tbody>
```